# Where to put custom sound file for push notifications in Ionic 2 for Android

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2

I am using the push plugin in my Ionic 2 app. Now I want to use a custom sound file.

I am sending the file name in my payload:

```
options = {data: {title: "Title", body: 'Body.', soundname: 'soundfile'}}
```

But now I don't know where to put the sound file in my Ionic project.

I am supposed to put it into res/raw. But is this inside my platform folder? Can someone tell me the correct path starting from the root directory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer:

You have to put it in:

```
platforms/android/res/raw/filename.mp3
```

For iOS I put it here:

```
platforms/ios/res/raw/filename.mp3
```

In your options it's important that you inform the filename WITHOUT the filetype:

```
options = {data: {title: "Title", body: 'Body.', soundname: 'filename'}}
```

Comment: And what do you do for iOS?

Comment: platforms/android/res/raw/ path not found ionic3

Answer (score 0):

platforms/android/res/raw/ path not found ionic3. What to do? Shall I have to create manually?

Comment: platforms/android/res/raw/ path not found ionic3. What to do? Shall I have to create manually?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59241344/1201322 See this