# How can I play the push notification more times in Ionic?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, ionic-native

How can I play the push notification more times in Ionic?

For example: When I received the push notification I would like to play the notification sound 3 times.

Comment: Refer to this Answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43207253/where-to-put-custom-sound-file-for-push-notifications-in-ionic-2-for-android

Answer (score 0):

You could create a custom notification sound for your app, and pass the name of the file along with the push notification content.

This is possible in ionic and i had done it myself before.

Please refer the docs for custom notification sound and create your app's notification accordingly. That will be easier.