# How to copy file to /res/raw using cordova plugin hook

Tags: android, cordova, plugins, hook

As the title suggests, I'm trying to build a cordova plugin for android (which is an empty plugin) which purpose is to copy a file into the /res/raw folder of the APK. This seems to be needed for Android so OneSignal can play custom ringtones upon receiving a notification. In order to achieve this, I'm using an hook for after_plugin_install and before_build. The content is the same, the difference is the folders. This hook is a modified version of [this one](https://gist.github.com/imagn8nmechanic/fb5eb60a73ec4b8c808c).

The reason why I'm using a plugin for this instead of adding the resource to the cordova project folder is because I don't have access to the cordova project folder. As such, my only "workaround" is using a plugin (with the hook) to do it.

An excerpt of the hook file:

```
// configure all the files to copy from each of the resource paths.
// key of object is the source file, value is the destination location.
// the directory/file structure used closely mirrors how the resources
// are stored in each platform
var androidFilesToCopy = {
  // android icons
  "android/beep.wav": "beep.wav"
};

// required node modules
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');
var rootdir = "plugins";
var buildDir = "build";

// android platform resource path
var platformAndroidPath = 'locales/android/raw/';
```

I've tested several values for the platformAndroidPath and several "hook timeline types" (before_build, after_build, before_prepare, etc.) but none seems to work. I also see that if I use "cordova plugin**s** add *location*" (plugins as plural), it detects the file. If I use "cordova plugin add *location*" (plugin as singular) it doesn't detect the file.

At this point I am a bit lost and really don't know where to go now. If anyone is able to provide some guidance, that would be utterly appreciated. The full plugin is [here](https://github.com/aportuguesecoder/cordova-plugin-custom-notification).

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on the version of cordova-android you're targeting, the path you're looking for will differ.

For example for `cordova platform add android@6.4.0` this is the overall folder structure:

```
├── hooks
├── platforms
│   └── android
│       ├── CordovaLib
│       ├── assets
│       ├── cordova
│       ├── libs
│       ├── platform_www
│       ├── res # <- this is the path you want!
│       └── src
├── plugins
├── res
└── www
```

Notice that res is right under "android" folder and that's where android resources live.

But, for `cordova platform add android@8.0.0`:

```
├── hooks
├── platforms
│   └── android
│       ├── CordovaLib
│       ├── app
│       │   └── src
│       │       └── main
│       │           ├── assets
│       │           ├── java
│       │           ├── libs
│       │           └── res # <- this is the path you want!
│       ├── cordova
│       └── platform_www
├── plugins
├── res
└── www
```

So, in practice, it depends on which cordova platform you're running your hook, but in general its like this:

- cordova-android < 7: `platforms/android/res/raw`
- cordova-android >= 7: `platforms/android/app/src/main/res/raw`

You can find a similar example [here](https://github.com/OutSystems/pushwoosh-phonegap-plugin/blob/1f44de3c23d4da406a74c549a9f9d50c4755e502/hooks/outsystems/handle_google_services.js#L58).